# Unable to check for password and username at login

Tags: php

I have tried to create a PHP log in form. My code is as follows. The if-else statement is not functioning well. Please solve this.

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //connect
    mysql_select_db("elective_mgmt", $connect);
    $username = $_GET["name"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];
    $query = "SELECT * from verify_student where 
      username='$username' && password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (name == $username && password == $password)
        echo "you are logged in";
    else 
        echo "please recheck your password and username";
```

Comment: Totally dirty code, I won't solve your issue as it will just make you even lazier..Instead I would suggest you to learn PHP first and than start writing your code... Also note, login will never be possible without sessions...

Comment: you are wide open for SQL injection. Also, by using `$_GET` you are putting `password` in the url.

Comment: what are the value of var_dump $username ,$password, $result.
this line is wrong 'if (name == $username && password == $password)'. Just think what is name ???? where it comes from..

Comment: Also, OP should be hashing the passwords at the very least.

Comment: use this link for better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956308/php-and-mysql-login-query

Comment: Your if condition is wrong. `name == $username` What is name ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
 echo "you are logged in";
}
    else 
        echo "please recheck your password and username";
```

You can also do this by counting the number of **rows**. In your code `$row` is an array  so whenver you need to acces the array elements do this `$row['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here.

```
if(name==$username && password==$password)
```

It should be

```
if($row['name']==$username && $row['password']==$password)
```

OR

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

**You should look at - [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1288198)**

Comment: Actually he should be using `mysql_num_rows()` to check whether the query returns 1, if yes than re direct else fail..

Comment: Great... Not the down voter here.. but again your condition is wrong, it should be `== 1` and not `>= 1` because we are talking about login system, where usernames has to be unique so there's no possibility of multiple returning rows

Comment: @ Ashwini . Again I couldn't find the solution. I tried this too !!

Comment: Thanks Ashiwini and Mr. Alien. I found the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove your if/else statement since you check the inputs already with your mysql query (name && password) and replace it with a mysql_num_rows == 1 (as the others have already mentioned before).

It seems that you are new to php and creating log in forms, so let me give you a good advice:

1. input values for a log in form shouldn't be passed via URL, use method post instead
2. never save passwords unencrypted (use sha512 since md5 is considered unsafe)
3. never use single information to store the log in status in the session